# issues with jquery-select2 and rails form validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm using the [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) jQuery plugin, on a rails form to do autocompleting on a multi-select field. Everything works fine if there are no validation errors on the page. If there is a validation error (not related to this element), then the javascript portion gets an empty element and fails on the JSON.parse call.

However inspecting with chrome-tools show that the Form Data has the correct information under services

```
services:[{"id":93,"text":"Old School"},{"id":94,"text":"Gels"}],93,94
```

Here is the view snippet

```
<%= f.label :services, "Services" %>
              <input name="services" type='hidden' id='services' data-values='<%= @services %>' value='<%= @selected_services %>' style="width: 100%"/>
```

The Javascript looks like this.

```
var initSel = function (element, callback) {
console.log("intiSel data BRFORE json parse", $(element).val());
try {
  var data = JSON.parse($(element).val());
  callback(data);
  console.log("intiSel data AFTER json parse", data);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Parsing error:", e);
}
```

}

```
$(function() {
  $("#services").select2({
    initSelection: initSel,
    createSearchChoice: function(term, data) {
      if ( $(data).filter(function() {
        return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
      }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};}
    },
    multiple: true,
    data: function (){
      var data = $('#services').data('values');
      return {results:data};
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, after validation error the select2 inputs fields were not able to load data.

I'm not sure that it will helps for your case but it can help other stack users with select2 error after validation.

In my case the error was coming from the controller. I was using a before_action filter to get  the variables to prepare the options or the data for the select2 inputs fields.

I realize that I was missing some actions in my filter, so the variables were not generated anymore.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :prepare_data, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :create] #now I had all my actions not only edit and new for instance.

  private 

  def prepare_data
   @my_var_for_data_select2 = User.all.collect.collect{|u| u.username}
  end
end
```